# Getting the default height for a UITabbar without creating an instance?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

Is there a way to get the default height for UITabBars?  I want to avoid hardcoding the value but would also like to avoid creating an instance of one to only get the height.  Below is how I'm currently getting the height, but it seems like there should be a more efficient way that doesn't involved creating a controller.

```
extension UITabBar {
    private static var storedHeight: CGFloat?
    @objc static var height: CGFloat {
        get {
            if let height = storedHeight { return height }
            storedHeight = UITabBarController().tabBar.frame.size.height
            return storedHeight ?? 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without creating you can 1. hardcode heights depending on device types; 2. calculate height and keep it globally

Comment: I'm trying to avoid hardcoding as stated, and in my current code I already calculate and store it for later use as shown but I feel that I shouldn't have to create a UITabBarController instance just to get it's tabBar height.